# How can I have a linq query conditionally NOT apply a where clause

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I don't even know how to word what I want, so here is some code!

```
//jobTerm
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.SelectedJobTerm))
{
    vacancies = vacancies.Where(x => (!x.IsExternalPost 
            && x.JobTerm.Name.Contains(vm.SelectedJobTerm)));
}
//jobType
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.SelectedJobType))
{
    vacancies = vacancies.Where(x => (!x.IsExternalPost 
            && x.JobType.Name.Contains(vm.SelectedJobType)));
}
```

What is happening above is I am running through a series of if statements, and adding to my linq query if certain things apply. I am deferring execution until the end. This is for a search results filter if that helps.

In the code above you see that I am trying to put in the Where clause that I want the query to not care about the vm.SelectedJobTerm or vm.SelectedJobType if the vacancy is an External post. I need this to apply to pretty much all my filters. The logic should go something like this

```
-Is there a value in vm.SomeValue?
|_____>Yes
|       |_____>Is this an external post?
|              |__>Yes->do not apply where clause
|              |   
|              |__>No->Apply the where clause stuff
|
|____>No-> Go about your business.
```

Is there a way to do this in linq?

I should note that I am hitting an azure database, so I cannot run this through a profiler. Flying a little blind.

Comment: Have you looked at Dynamic Linq?

Comment: Is "Go about your business" the same as "do not apply where clause" ?

Comment: Is what you've got actually not working or is it just that you want a shorter way to write it without having to duplicate the condition every time?

Comment: @thepirat000 yeah, i'll edit.

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush, I have heard of DLINQ before, how could it help in this scenario?

Comment: @Chris it is not working.

Comment: Are you in actual fact just trying to grab all jobs that are external posts and jobs that contain the selectedjobterm? i.e. vacancies.Where(x => x.IsExternalPost || x.JobTerm.Name.Contains(vm.SelectedJobTerm))

Comment: You have to use OR `||`

Comment: @everyone. damn it... it was the || operator and some parens that I needed... Thanks for pointing out my embarrassing oversight!

Comment: Rather than using dynamic link, expressions can be an excellent way to go in this situation.  There are a few out there, but I like Pete Montgomery's [Predicate Builder](http://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're currently excluding records where `IsExternalPost == true`.

This will include them:

```
vacancies = vacancies.Where(x =>
    x.IsExternalPost || x.JobTerm.Name.Contains(vm.SelectedJobTerm));
```

Comment: I think you mean including?

Comment: @failedprogramming: I think Grant is saying that in the original post they are excluding them which is their problem whereas the OP is suggesting that he wants to keep them in his text.

Answer (score 4):

How about using [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)?

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<MyClass>();

//jobTerm
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.SelectedJobTerm))
    predicate = predicate.And(x => x.JobType.Name.Contains(vm.SelectedJobType));

//jobType
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.SelectedJobType))
    predicate = predicate.And(x => x.JobType.Name.Contains(vm.SelectedJobType));

predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.IsExternalPost);
vacancies = vacancies.Where(predicate);
```

Comment: Ha!  I just posted this as a comment.  +1

Answer (score 1):

Grant's post is correct, but can be simplified due to the way lazy loading is performed with the `||` operator (if the first part is true, it won't even check for or care about the second part):

```
vacancies = vacancies.Where(x => x.IsExternalPost 
                                || x.JobTerm.Name.Contains(vm.SelectedJobTerm));
```

Or if you want to check for both conditions in the same query:

```
vacancies = vacancies.Where(x => x.IsExternalPost
                                || x.JobTerm.Name.Contains(vm.SelectedJobTerm)
                                || x.JobType.Name.Contains(vm.SelectedJobType));
```